# How to pass a file path to rosrun?

Tags: ros, lsd-slam, rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the syntax for passing a filepath as a parameter to rosrun?

I'm trying to call [lsd_slam_core](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) with a custom calibration file located at lsd_slam_test/config/logitech.cfg with:

```
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/usb_cam/image_mono camera_info:=/usb_cam/camera_info calib:=lsd_slam_test/config/logitech.cfg
```

but this returns the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
  what():  Character [.] at element [25] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [lsd_slam_test/config/logitech.cfg].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208729/how-to-pass-a-file-path-to-rosrun?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

put  `_`  before calib

```
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/usb_cam/image_mono camera_info:=/usb_cam/camera_info _calib:=lsd_slam_test/config/logitech.cfg
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to pass the argument via commandline with `rosrun`, the way @bvbdort suggests should be the way to go.

In addition, when passing a file path in general I recommend to pass absolute paths compensated by tools like `rospack find`. Combined, your command would look like the following (not sure if this is exactly what you do):

```
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/usb_cam/image_mono camera_info:=/usb_cam/camera_info _calib:=`rospack find lsd_slam_test`/config/logitech.cfg
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1